# Stuck in async loop with wrapAsync

Tags: loops, asynchronous, meteor, server

My goal is to go through a loop asynchronously:

`client.js`:

```
abc = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 49; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        Meteor.call('testBla', i)
    }
}
```

server.js

```
testBla: function(i) {
                function asyncCall() {
                    console.log('inside asyncCall', i)
                    return 'done';
                }
                var syncCall = Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncCall);
                console.log('a');
                var res = syncCall(i);
                console.log('b')
                return res;
            }
```

Console:

```
a
inside asyncCall 0
```

Why does it stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions you can pass to `Meteor.wrapAsync` must have a specific signature : their arguments must end with a callback given 2 arguments : error and result.

Inside an async function body, you must invoke the callback with either an error in case the function fails, or the result if everything is OK.

```
function asyncHelloWorld(callsCount, callback){
  // simulate fake error every 5 calls
  if(callsCount % 5 === 0){
    callback("error");
  }
  callback(null,);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  asyncHelloWorld(i, function(error, result){
    if(error){
      console.log(error.reason);
      return;
    }
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

You can only wrap functions that respect this signature and behavior, which is a standard inherited from Node.JS.

When you wrap async functions, don't forget to use a try/catch block if you want to handle the potential error.

```
Meteor.methods({
  helloWorld: function(i){
    var syncHelloWorld = Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncHelloWorld);
    console.log("a");
    try{
      var res = syncHelloWorld(i);
      console.log("b")
      return res;
    }
    catch(exception){
      console.log(exception);
      console.log("c");
      // do not recover, propagates the exception back to the client (standard behavior)
      throw exception;
    }
  }
});
```