# Meteor wrapAsync executes synchronously but never returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I'm trying to wrap a function from a node package with wrapAsync.

```
filepicker = new Filepicker('API Key') 
filepickerStatSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(filepicker.stat, filepicker)
result = filepickerStatSync(url);
console.log('after')
```

The stat function is below.

Everything seem to work fine... the request call responds with the correct result, the final callback is called, the whole thing executes synchronously / yields correctly as far as I can tell... but the sync call never returns and console.log('after') is never hit.

I don't think I made the same mistake as happened in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server) because my function has a callback as the last parameter.

I also don't think the solution is in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442972/meteor-stuck-in-async-loop-with-wrapasync) because the wrapped function does end with calling the callback with error and result, which is supposedly what Meteor.wrapAsync is looking for in a signature.

```
Filepicker.prototype.stat = function(url, options, callback) {
    callback = callback || function(){};
    if(!options) {
        options = {};
    }
    if(!url) {
        callback(new Error('Error: no url given'));
        return; 
    }
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url+'/metadata?',
        form: {
            size: options.size || true,
            mimetype: options.mimetype || true,
            filename: options.filename || true,
            width: options.width || true,
            height: options.height || true,
            writeable: options.writeable || true,
            md5: options.md5 || true,
            path: options.path || true,
            container: options.container || true,
            security: options.security || {}
        }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log('err = '+err);
        console.log('res = '+res);
        console.log('body = '+body);
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        var returnJson;
        if(typeof(body)==='string'){
            try {
                returnJson = JSON.parse(body);
             } catch(e) {
                callback(new Error('Unknown response'), null, body);
                return;
             }
        } else {
            console.log('returnJSON');
            returnJson = body;
        }
        console.log('callbacked');
        callback(null, returnJson);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are wrapping takes three arguments, but you are only providing two: `url`, and (implicitly) the callback function (I'll call it `cb`). So internally, what will get executed is `Filepicker.prototype.stat(url, cb)`, i.e., the callback function `cb` will get interpreted as the `options` rather than the `callback`, and `callback` will be set to an empty function. So the callback of wrapAsync is never called, because the callback chain was broken.

This should work:

```
result = filepickerStatSync(url, {});
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. Silly oversight on my part. I'll come back and award the bounty when the system lets me. Cheers!